# $Spec(R)$ finite and discrete implies $R_{red}$ Artinian proof verification

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, zariski-topology, artinian

My proof feels weird to me because I on the way prove that an Artinian ring with trivial nilradical is a product of division rings, and I can't find this result anywhere, so even though I am quite confident in my proof, it is giving me doubts.

Because $Spec(R)=Spec(R_{red})$, we can assume $R$ has no nilpotent elements. Let $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the set of all prime ideals. Because $Spec(R)$ is discrete every prime ideal is maximal, in particular two distinct prime ideals are coprime. Also the intersection of all prime ideals is 0. So by the chinese remainder theorem:

$$R\cong \prod_{i=1}^n R/p_i$$

Which is a product of division rings (because the $p_i$ are maximal), a finite product of division rings is clearly Artinian, finishing the proof.

Is this proof valid? Or is my hunch that I did something fishy, and if so how can I fix my proof? (note I am not assuming commutativity).

Comment: Do you know Artin-Wedderburn theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem

Comment: A commutative Artinian ring with trivial nilradical _is_ a finite product of fields.  The version commonly taught in classical noncommutative algebra is "A semiprime right artinian ring is semisimple."  In the case of commutative rings, semisimple rings are finite products of fields.  (You should refer to Wedderburn-Artin as already suggested.)